# The difference between 2 arrays in c++ A\B

Tags: c++

So I have 2 arrays. Let's say the first one it's called a and the second one b. The first one uses "i" for it's elements and the second one uses "j".
For example we have a[ 1 2 3 4] and b[3 4 5]  it should show c[1 2]. In the array c I want to show the elements that are in a and aren't in b.
This is what I've tried, but without succes:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int a[50], b[50], c[50], i, j, k, n, m;
    cout << "n= "; cin >> n;

    //Read arrays
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "a[" << i << "]: "; cin >> a[i];
    }
    cout << "\nm= "; cin >> m;
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        cout << "b[" << j << "]: "; cin >> b[j];
    }

    //Show the arrays
    cout << endl;
    cout << "\na[ ";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "]";

    cout << endl;
    cout << "\nb[ ";
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        cout << b[j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "]";

    //Calculate the difference
    k = 0; i = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        if (a[i] != b[j])
            c[k] = a[i];
        k++;
        while (j == m && i < n)
            i++;
    }

    //Show the difference array
    cout << endl;
    cout << "\nc[ ";
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        cout << c[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "]";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Can the items in the array be sorted?

Answer (score 5):

If the items are sorted, use [std::set_difference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference):

```
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iterator>
    #include <vector>

    int main()
    {
       int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
       int b[] = { 3, 4, 5 };
       std::vector<int> cv;
       std::set_difference(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 
                           std::begin(b), std::end(b), 
                           std::back_inserter(cv));
       for (auto& s : cv)
         std::cout << s << "\n";
    }

Output:
1
2
```

The advantage of using the STL algorithms is that the purpose of the code is known immediately just by looking at the name of the function, and that they work every time (if you give them the correct parameters).  Note the lack of comments -- any competent C++ programmer understands right away what's being done.

On the other hand, if you didn't mention what your original code was trying to do (including removing the comments), it would take much more effort to figure out what it's supposed to be doing, and as you've seen, it contains bugs.

Comment: If you look at the answer (not just the code), there are links to the requisite function (std::set_difference).  The OP can go there and learn about this and other algorithm functions.  Also, if someone were to do a search on SO for this topic of finding the difference in two arrays, they have this answer that is simple, and again, has pertinent hyperlinks to the information required to know what the function does.  If you want to take the OP's original code, then prepare to go through it with a fined-tooth comb and point out all errors (which I have done in other questions on SO).

Comment: @coderredoc: It has nothing to do with a user's reputation. I didn't see this answer at the time. Don't take everything so personally all the time.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit.: I didn't mean you but the other DV supports my logic...I said you before and now also..I didn't mean you and if I by any means said wrong ...It's my fault  indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong.

### Explanation

So the thing that we will do

1. For each element in `a` we will have to check if it is there in array `b` or not.
2. If we see any element of `a[i]` in `b[1..m]` then we can't add it to `c`.
   So in code we just mark it by `f=1`
3. When I get out of that second `for` loop I want to check if that `a[i]` is eqaul to any of the element in `b[1..m]` in which case f will be `1`. But if it is `0` then add it to array `c[]`.

### Correct one

```
int k=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  int f=0;
  for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
    if(a[i]==b[j])
       f=1;
  if(!f)
    c[k++]=a[i];

}
```

### Where OP went wrong?

Being not equal to one element of `b[]` doesn't guarantee that the element is not appearing `b[0..m-1]` . This is where op went wrong.
 In the for loop 
`for(j=0;j<m;j++)` you are checking if particular `a[i]` is equal to `b[j]` or not. If that is the case then it is added to `c[]` . It is wrong. Also `i` is not incremented in the loop unless `j==m` and as in the for loop the condition is `j<m` so `i` is never incremented. And `k` is incremented every time so not every element in `c` is valid they may contain garbage value even after processing.

```
k = 0; i = 0;
for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    if (a[i] != b[j]) // this doesn't mean that it is not appearing in `b`
        c[k] = a[i];
    k++;              // k is incremented in every iteration which is wrong. It should be only when we are sure that `a[i]` is not in `b[0..m-1] `
    while (j == m && i < n) 
        i++;          // OP is not using it anywhere...this is redundant.
}
```

### what op did?

Compared first element of `a[0]` with every element of `b[0..m-1]` and array `c[]` contains `m` elements irrespective of what `a[]` and `b[]` is, out of which

```
c[i]={ a[0] if b[j]==a[0]
     { garbage value if b[j] not equal to a[0]
```

### Dry Run of OP's code

```
     k = 0; i = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (a[i] != b[j])
                c[k] = a[i];
            k++;
            while (j == m && i < n)
                i++;
        }

    Input
    Case: 1 2 3 4 :a[]
          2 3 4 1 :b[]

Step 1:  i=0 a[0]!=b[0] is true so c[0]=a[0]. the `while loop` not entered.
         j++

Step-2: i is still 0. a[0]!=b[1] so it is added c[1]=a[0]. While loop not  entered.
         j++
Step-3: i is still 0. a[0]!=b[2]. So c[2]=a[0]. While loop skipped.
         j++
Step-4: i is still 0. a[0]==b[3] is true so no assignment done. But k is incremented. so c[3]=garbage. j=3 so while loop skipped 
         j++
Out of for loop.

Output: [here x is garbage value]
    a[]: 1 2 3 4
    b[]: 2 3 4 1
    c[]: 1 2 3 x
```

### Example test case

```
1 2 3 4 :=a
2 3 4 1 :=b
```

### Corrected Code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

int a[50], b[50], c[50], i, j, k, n, m;
cout << "n= "; cin >> n;

//Read arrays
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << "a[" << i << "]: "; cin >> a[i];
}
cout << "\nm= "; cin >> m;
for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    cout << "b[" << j << "]: "; cin >> b[j];
}

//Show the arrays
cout << endl;
cout << "\na[ ";
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << a[i] << " ";
}
cout << "]";

cout << endl;
cout << "\nb[ ";
for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    cout << b[j] << " ";
}
cout << "]";

//Calculate the difference
k = 0; i = 0;
int k=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   int f=0;
   for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
   {
      if(a[i]==b[j])
          f=1;
      if(!f)
          c[k++]=a[i];
   }
}
//Show the difference array
cout << endl;
cout << "\nc[ ";
for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    cout << c[i] << " ";
}
cout << "]";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But I'm just wondering what's wrong with what I was thinking. I thought this: If an element in a[i] it's equal to an element in b[j] then do nothing with it, just leave it be, otherwise put that element in the array c[k]. And increment k by 1 with each element found in a[i] that isn't in b[j]

Comment: I already explained why I downvoted, and it has nothing to do with not using the standard library. I haven't read your updated answer yet.

Comment: You're still not explaining what was wrong about the OP's original approach.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie.: If you get time maybe you can go through my answer once...?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit.: Would you please instruct me if I need some kind of modification..I am not asking you mutiple times to get upvotes or remove my DV's..you don't have to remove it..just if possible check my answer and suggest if there is anything more which needs to be modified.

Comment: @Zenyte.: I have added why your solution didn't work..ask me if you don't understand anything

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit.: Would you mind reading my answer once? I have added everything.

Comment: It's better. Not the clearest answer I've ever seen but at least it's complete now. Please stop pinging me all the time

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit.: It's really amazing to see that you have removed your DV..because many a times downvoters don't get back to check the answer again. I guess I will modify or shorten the answer more to get to the point...If you ever go through my answer again you will see..Thanks for the help and really earlier I didn't mean anything against (if it sounded like that)..Thanks you very much. Some people they do downvote without any idea or proper back up reason that's why I said that. Giving some time after answer ..I am sure I will edit it... That's all. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to check if the elements in `a` are equal to all elements of `b`. If you just want to check the elements in `a` if they are equal to at least one element of `b`, you can do

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  bool found = false;
  for (int j=0; j<m; j++) {
    if (a[i] == b[j]) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!found) {
    std::cout << "a["<<i<<"] is not in b"<<std::endl;
  }
}
```

Or add the element to `c`, but I would recommend to use `std::vector<int> c` for that.

Answer (score 0):

> In the array `c` I want to show the elements that are in `a` and aren't in `b`

It seems like you are looking for `std::set_difference`

```
int a[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4}, b[3] = {3, 4, 5};
int c[2] = {}; // declare c with enough space to hold all the elements in result

std::set_difference(a, a + 4, b, b + 3, c); // now c contains the element that are in a but not in b
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this very easily using 'set'.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
int main(){
    std::set<int> a = {1,2,3,4} , b = {3,4,5};
    for(int const inB : b)
        a.erase(inB);
    for(int const inA : a)
        std::cout << inA << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```